# Maximum frequency of sine wave generated using AD9833 and arduino

Tags: arduino, waveform

AD9833 can generate sine wave with frequency ranging from 0 to 12.5MHz. I want to make the sine generator using AD9833 and Arduino. What is the maximum frequency of the output sine wave possible in this case?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 12.5 MHz, as you say. What's your question here?

Comment: How accurate a sine wave shape do you need?

Comment: @Andyaka I think we're both thinking the same, but we might be leading OP too far here. I'd like to understand what Ananya is actually wondering about. They already read the datasheet, it seems, so they can piece together that, yes, 12.5 MHz is achievable. So, I'm really confused what the question is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think 12.5 MHz won’t be a sine wave of acceptable quality and I’m trying to hint that this needs to be considered.

Comment: @Andyaka yeah, I was thinking in the same direction, but I honestly don't know whether this question is more about the Arduino side (which would boil down to "how do I generate a clock"?) or to the AD9833 side ("how to program the thing") or to the signal side ("what is a sine wave, anyway?", which is what the both of us would like to point out). It's hard to know what to answer here – maybe OP is aware of a 2-samples-per-period DDS not being great, and knows the necessary reconstruction filtering. Maybe not.

Comment: I wanted to know if this high frequency is supported by Arduino or not.

Comment: The arduino has directly nothing to do with the frequency that IC generates @AnanyaSrivastava; it just sets a few registers in the AD9833 that tells it to generate some frequency. The Arduino *could* be a source of the clock that the AD9833 needs, but you don't tell us anything about how you plan to clock the AD9833, so this is all guesswork. also, "Arduino" is kind of a blanket term for **very** different devices, so you'll have to tell us more.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I plan to clock the ad9833 with a digital pin Arduino. I saw this connection when I checked the net.

Comment: again, which arduino? "Arduino" is a class of software-loaded devices, and I can't tell you which clocks these can generate without you telling us which arduino (is it really hard to understand why?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nano

Comment: so, ask yourself whether the arduino nano has a microcontroller that can output a 25 MHz clock. I'll have to look up the data sheet as much as you would have to.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get started playing with a 9833 is to buy a module with a 25MHz clock oscillator already on it. These can be had for as little as £2 on a well known auction site. The module has serial interface pins to plug into an Arduino (or any other flavour of controller you want).

You would then program your Arduino to run some form of user interface to set a number corresponding to frequency, then manipulate that number so that it can program the 9833 registers, then send the serial information to the 9833 via the SPI interface. That's all just software, any limitations are those you choose, and are purely numeric. The speed at which data is clocked into the 9833 is entirely controlled by the Arduino, it's completely separate for the sinewave generation side.

What you do need to provide is the output anti-alias filter, and this will mdefine your output frqeuency. Although the module has a 25MHz clock, and the 9833 can 'generate up to 12.5MHz', you need an anti-alias filter to reconstruct the waveform that it outputs.

The complexity of the filter increases as the frequency you want to generate increases. For 0-3MHz for instance, the filter passes 3MHz and stops (25-3) = 22MHz. For 10MHz output, it would pass 10MHz, and stop (25-10) = 15MHz. The complexity of this second filter is not 3x that of the first, but 4x, as it's based on the transition band, not the passband. If you wanted a 12MHz output, the filter would pass 12MHz and stop (25-12) = 13MHz. This filter is 19x the complexity of the 3MHz filter.